# SQL transform data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have results coming from a query in the below format

```
ID CODE
----------
 1   abc
 1   xyz
 1   def
 1   pqr
 1   jkl
 1   tuv
```

I want the results to be in the following format

```
ID CODE1 CODE2 CODE3 CODE4 CODE5 CODE6
---------------------------------------
1  abc   xyz   def   pqr   jkl   tuv
```

I know this can be achieved using static `PIVOT` query, but the issue I am facing is that the `CODE` column can have unknown values and I want my column names to be fixed i.e. `CODE1`, `CODE2` and so on 'til `CODE6`.

Can someone please help me out with this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: post your query please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a PivotTable in Transact/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617713/how-to-create-a-pivottable-in-transact-sql)

Comment: Personally I find the syntax for Pivot to be very obtuse. I prefer to use a dynamic crosstab for this sort of thing. Here is an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211349/sql-pivot-possible-for-this-data-set/43212010#43212010

Comment: @SeanLange You can never go wrong with Moden. And it probably performs a lot better than it looks like it should. And after you remove the tallyTable code, it's not as complex as it looks. I'll have to remember that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be a fairly simple PIVOT using a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function. I threw in a 7th `CODE` for `ID` 1 to show that it will be ignored if you're only pivoting 6 columns, however, because your `OVER` isn't deterministic (it can `ORDER` any way it wants since it only uses `ID`), it *could* pick up a different set of 6 `CODE`s.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ddcde/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 ( ID int, _CODE varchar(20) ) ;
INSERT INTO t1 (ID, _CODE)
VALUES 
    (1,'abc')
  , (1,'xyz')
  , (1,'def')
  , (1,'pqr')
  , (1,'jkl')
  , (1,'tuv')
  , (2,'lmn')
  , (2,'rgb')
  , (1,'ignoredOnly6')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT piv.ID
  , piv.[1] AS CODE1
  , piv.[2] AS CODE2
  , piv.[3] AS CODE3
  , piv.[4] AS CODE4 
  , piv.[5] AS CODE5 
  , piv.[6] AS CODE6
FROM (
  SELECT t1.ID, t1._CODE
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.ID) AS rn
  FROM t1
) s1
PIVOT (
  max(s1._CODE) 
  FOR s1.rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]) 
) piv
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ddcde/1/0)**:

```
| ID | CODE1 | CODE2 |  CODE3 |  CODE4 |  CODE5 |  CODE6 |
|----|-------|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|  1 |   abc |   xyz |    def |    pqr |    jkl |    tuv |
|  2 |   lmn |   rgb | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Comment: NOTE: I also used table aliases so you can see where the values are coming from in the query. I will agree with Sean, `PIVOT`s can get a bit wonky.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.Much appreciated.

Comment: My over actually has 3 columns so will this query change by any way?

Comment: How do you mean? You can have multiple columns that don't get pivoted in the `s1` subquery. That will change how your window is partitioned (`rn`).

Comment: Yes I have total 4 columns in my sub query, out of which code is pivoted.

Comment: It depends on how those columns relate to each other. They'll all need to be in the outer (and inner) `SELECT`. You can write out the query in `s1` to pull the data that you want. The `ROW_NUMBER()` is supposed to give you a number 1-6 to `PIVOT` in the outer query.